# Is hint({$natural: 1}) redundant when using a tailable cursor?

Tags: mongodb, capped-collections

In many examples I find for using tailable cursors on capped collections, the code includes:

```
hint( { $natural: 1 } )
```

(e.g. [here](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2013/04/mongodb-pubsub-with-capped-collections.html)), including the official docs ([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/)), to "ensure we don't use any indexes", and that results are returned in natural (i.e. disk) order.

However, the docs also suggest this is the default behavior of tailable cursors:

> Tailable cursors do not use indexes and return documents in natural order.

So **is the use of the `hint` redundant**?

I tried looking at the output of `explain()` with and without the `hint`, and as far as I can tell, there was no difference.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is if you have an index, since the tail *must* use natural order, the hint must be specified to avoid using the other index.

Comment: @joao I would have thought so, but the docs say: "Tailable cursors do not use indexes"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

What you might want to do sometimes is to return the result in reverse natural order (the last document inserted the first to be returned. You can achieve this by:

```
db.cappedCollection.find().sort({$natural:-1})
```

effectively changing the FIFO nature of a capped collection to a LIFO nature.